# XML to MySQL with php

Tags: php, xml

I have a field in my xml like this :

```
<radar snb="09H0000" ver="1023" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="icomsData.xsd">
```

How can get the variable "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation"

My code to get "snb" and "ver" works fine but not for the 2 others :/

My code :

```
    $fichier = 'test.xml'; 

    $radar = simplexml_load_file($fichier);

    echo '</br> Radar : 
        </br> snb : <strong>'.$radar['snb'].' </strong>ver : <strong>'.$radar['ver'].'</strong> xmlns:xsi : <strong>'.$radar['xmlns:xsi'].' </strong> xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation : <strong>'.$radar['xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation'].'</strong>';
```

I tried with " and ' it doesn't change anything.

Comment: which variable from xml do you want to use ?

Comment: All the variables even if they are useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code to access variables in xml file :

```
<?php

$xmlFile = 'test.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
$radarAttr = $xml->attributes();
$noNamespaceSchemaLocation = $xml->attributes('xsi', true)->noNamespaceSchemaLocation->__tostring();
$radarSnb  = $radarAttr['snb']->__tostring();
$radarVer  = $radarAttr['ver']->__tostring();

foreach($xml->log as $log) {
    $LogAttrs = $log->attributes();
    $logTs = $LogAttrs['ts']->__tostring();
    $logVb = $LogAttrs['vb']->__tostring();

    $site = $log->site->__tostring();

    $evArray = $log->ev;
    foreach($evArray as $ev) {
        $EvAttrs = $ev->attributes();
        $evTs = $EvAttrs['ts']->__tostring();

        $evData = $ev->children();

        $ev_sp = $evData->sp->__tostring();
        $ev_lg = $evData->lg->__tostring();
        $ev_dir = $evData->dir->__tostring();
    }


}
```

Comment: Awesome mate, you did almost all the job for me ^^ Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For this solution you  would need to take these step as follows

1. First write a script that convert all xml files to CSV format.
2. Make a script that upload CSV file to DB.

Comment: I would have see more like : The script reads the "xml" then I do directly the INSERT query when I finished to read.